# AWS SDK check if object exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In `AmazonS3Client` there is a method `doesObjectExist(String bucketName, String objectName)`. This method throws an `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request;` if you are calling it for an encrypted object. Any other way to check if an object exists, without knowing the encryption key that was used when saving it? I do not want to access the object without having the encryption key, I just want to know if an object named 'blabla' exists or not, so I can prompt an error message to a client that wants to upload an object called 'blabla'.

Answer (score 2):

You could list all elements within the bucket and check if your object is there. even better with the `withPrefix` method you can limit the response

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
.withBucketName(bucketName)
.withPrefix("blabla");
```

You can also look at [`getObjectSummaries()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#getObjectSummaries()) method to know more about the returned object